# How to get current locale's "short_date_format" on django?

Tags: django, localization

I have L10N successfuly set up on my project, and I'm able to translate dates to the correct format. But now I need the `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` for the current locale on my templates, or in a context_processor.

Getting it from `django.conf.settings` always gives me the default value, `m/d/Y`.
The locale was currently set to `pt_BR`, so the format should be `d/m/Y`.

```
In [42]: settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
Out[42]: 'pt-br'

In [43]: settings.USE_L10N
Out[43]: True

In [44]: settings.SHORT_DATE_FORMAT
Out[44]: 'm/d/Y'
```

Any clues?

By the way, what I'm really trying to do is: get the current locale's format so I can pass it to bootstrap-datepicker plugin. It's currently using `m/d/Y` and django is giving a date in the `d/m/Y` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using [babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/BabelDjango):

`settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'babeldjango.middleware.LocaleMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

`context_processors.py`:

```
def global_context(request):
    # Fixing the date format so bootstrap-datepicker understands.
    js_frm = request.locale.date_formats['medium'].pattern

    context = {
    ...

    return context
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to do the following:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import formats 

correct_format = formats.get_format("SHORT_DATE_FORMAT", lang=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

Comment: You are using the LANGUAGE_CODE setting from the settings module which makes it not dynamic (it is the default language code used when Django cannot determine it in another way). In a view you can use request.LANGUAGE_CODE. Otherwise django.utils.translation.get_language()